# ROR + Ruby Date in Different Format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, date

If I have `@today = Thu Apr 21 2011 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (IST),`

How do I convert `@today` into `"Thur April 21, 2011"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Time.now.strftime("%a %B %d, %Y")
=> "Fri April 15, 2011"
```

In your occasion :

```
@today.to_time.strftime("%a %B %d, %Y")
=> "Thu April 21, 2011"
```