# Returning a string according to the arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I write a function:

```
mymessage("2011-02-27", "Aravind")
```

that will return

> Hello Aravind, you entered the following date: Friday February 27, 2011

Comment: Are you new to ruby as well? I suggest you learn ruby first, that way you have a good foundation to build your rails knowledge on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Rails works with a model view controller design pattern, so ideally, to do this, you would need to create code in all three components.

For simplicity, i will assume that you want to do this inside a helper, and i will only write the method. First of all, take a look at how you can construct the date :

[ROR + Ruby Date in Different Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674260/ror-ruby-date-in-different-format/5674376#5674376)

Now, your function could be like :

```
def mymessage(the_date, name)
  formatted_date = the_date.to_time.strftime("%A %B %d, %Y")
  "Hello #{name}, you entered the following date: #{formatted_date}"
end
```

Comment: maybe better put this method in the model?

Comment: This is how i begin my answer :)

Comment: Much better that my solution, I must need more coffee when I'm forgetting strftime.

Comment: @Mikhail if you leave it in the controller then you loose the ability to reuse the code somewhere else. Although I suppose that defeats the purpose of YAGNI since he only needs it in one place right now.

Comment: This doesn't belong in the controller.

Comment: If you're saving this string to the dv it should go in the model, otherwise it should be a view helper

Answer (score 1):

```
def mymessage(date,name)
  "Hello #{name}, you entered the following date: #{date}"
end
```